# Making layers invisible with mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, layer, invisible

Is it possible to make it so that when you click on a button the first time, a specific layer will become invisible... and then once you click on the button a second time, a different layer would become invisible, and so on? If so could I see an example? Thanks!

**What I've tried :**

```
/************************* RESET BUTTON **************************/ 
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reset); 

function reset(e:Event) : void 
{ 
    eraserClip.graphics.clear(); 
    initEraser();

    erasableBitmapData.fillRect(erasableBitmapData.rect, 0xFFFFFFFF); 
    penny.visible = true; 
    maskee4.visible = true; 
    card.visible = false; 
    greencard.visible = true;

}
```

The idea is, once I hit the reset button once, the layer named `card`, will disappear. Underneath that a layer will be there, which is titled `greencard`. Once I hit the reset button a second time I want the `greencard` to disappear. As you see above, I was just doing `(property name).visible = false;`. 
 This works for the first card but not any after because they would not appear.

Comment: All of the above is possible,  but do you have a snippet of code that you have tried that you can show us? Without some guidelines (existing code), the answers are endless.

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate layer visibility through ActionScript 3, since layers are a part of the IDE, not the movie. Instead, you'll have to use MovieClip objects, combined with button events.

Comment: Below is the code for the reset button. So the idea is, once I hit the reset button once, the layer named card, will disappear. Underneath that a layer will be there, which is titled greencard. Once I hit the reset button a second time I want the greencard to disappear. As you see below I was just doing (property name):visible=false;  That works for the first card but not any after because they would not appear. See below.

Comment: /*************************
RESET BUTTON
**************************/

reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reset);

function reset(e:Event):void {
 
  
 eraserClip.graphics.clear();
 initEraser();
 erasableBitmapData.fillRect(erasableBitmapData.rect, 0xFFFFFFFF);
 penny.visible=true;
 maskee4.visible=true;
 card.visible=false;
 greencard.visible=true;

Comment: You have to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try something like this below :

```
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset); 

var clickCount : int = 0; //# start with zero since no clicks yet

card.visible = true; 
greencard.visible = true;

function reset(e:Event) : void 
{ 
    clickCount += 1; //# adds +1 to current count of clicks

    eraserClip.graphics.clear(); 
    initEraser();

    erasableBitmapData.fillRect(erasableBitmapData.rect, 0xFFFFFFFF); 
    penny.visible = maskee4.visible = true; //# if same value (true) you can chain them like this

    if ( clickCount == 1) //if now 1 click
    { 
        card.visible = false; 
    }

    if ( clickCount == 2) //if now 2 clicks
    { 
        greencard.visible = false; 
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried putting this in and it still isn't working...I will go off what you gave me though. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad it's sorted. Remember as well you might need (or want) to reset `clickCount` after you have those 2 clicks. So in another function eg:  **start_Next_Game** it becomes `clickCount = 0; card.visible = true;  greencard.visible = true;`

Comment: Thanks! Another problem I have been running into is how to make it so that every time the user clicks on the reset button, that the game saves it's data...so that the user doesn't go back to the very first card each time they open the game again.

Comment: Look up **AS3 shared objects** as one option. Here is a quick **[tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/)**. Making games is not my main area though so look up more options via web search.